# Find maxima and minima of data like {time,value}

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of time and values of the charge and discharge of a capacitor, and i want to separate in two list of {time,value of charge} , {time, value of discharge}

I know there is a lot of the issue, but everything i read is only in a list of values. I'm interested to find the time that those peaks happened.

If my data is `data={{ti,vi}...}` i can do `FindPeaks[data[[;;,2]]]` but :

1. i'm want the maximum values and the minimum
2. the peaks i get do not come with the time that happened

Comment: Aren't they showing basically an exponential behavior? Or are they NKCs (New Kind of Capacitors? :D )

Comment: Do you want local or global minima/maxima?

Answer (score 1):

To find minima, run the same command with your data negated. To find the times and values, do

```
Transpose[{data[[PeakDetect[data]], 1]], FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]]}]
```

Comment: Wich is the difference between PeakDetect and FindPeaks?

Comment: The documentation is quite specific on this point. The first finds the indices of the peaks...